# Cross Platform code resuse with Monotouch - but what about app.config?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, cross-platform

System.Configuration is not supported on Monotouch; that actually means you cannot use app.config file types in your project. However, if you have an existing application that is using this .NET feature big time, what to do?

Any suggestions how to deal with it? Ideal situation is that app.config can be kept as it is and that Monotouch can read the settings as defined. In the end, that would mean a kind of implementation of System.Configuration.

Suggestions? Code? Would be more than welcome!

Answer (score 2):

MonoTouch's main difference from the standard .NET is to drop support for System.Configuration, in the same way that Silverlight did.

The reason is that this is a pretty heavy framework and it is not an opt-in feature.   If we were to support app.config, we would have to bring System.Configuration even for applications that did not care about, bloating the result.

The solution is to remove the dependency on app.config from your software, in the same way that you would if you used WinRT, .NET on Xbox or Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should realize that MonoTouch is not meant to make apps portable, just to enable developers to use C# for iOS apps.

The obvious thing you can do is to wrap this part into your own configuration management code and reimplement the missing part on the iOS side.

BTW the guys at Xamarin are working to create cross-platform APIs for iOS, WP and Android but I doubt these include configuration. They are meant to support device APIs like camera, compass, etc. and I am not really sure how far they have progressed.

Answer (score 0):

We ported the [OpenNETCF.Configuration code from the SDF](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework.aspx) (and by "ported" I mean simply created a MonoDroid and MonoTouch project file and imported the code files) and it works fine.  Of course it's a subset of the full Configuration namespace, but it provided pretty much everything we were using from the app.config files.

The code comes with the Standard and above editions, though if you're cheap I'm fairly sure the code changed very little from the 1.x code base which is free and at the bottom of the above linked page.